# Want to upload the non-versioned files/folders in a Repository on Visual SVN

Tags: svn, migration, repository, visualsvn-server, visualsvn

I want to upload few folders and files in a repository on Visual SVN server.
I want to do it using any command like import in SVN.

After Google, I found that Import command is useful for the same but I am getting an error "post of  E175013 in Visual SVN 403 forbidden".

Can anyone suggest and guide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "403 Forbidden" error indicates that your user account does not
have enough access permissions to access the repository URL you entered.

- Make sure that VisualSVN Server administrator gave you Read or Read/Write access to the repository or a project you attempt to access.
- Make sure that the URL you use to access the repository is correct. It's worth noting that URLs for Subversion repositories are *case-sensitive* and path-based access rules are case-sensitive as well.